# Custom attribute crashing on toJSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to determine which position the order is in to generate a order id, but this crashes laravel, nothing in the logs, just a 500 error in the browser:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Load extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    protected $appends = ['order_no'];

    public function workorder() 
    { 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\WorkOrder', 'work_order_id'); 
    }

    public function getOrderNoAttribute()
    {
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($this->workorder->loads as $load) {
            if ($load->id == $this->id) {
                break;
            }
            $count++;
        }
        return $this->workorder->id . "-" . $count;
    }
}
```

When I changed it to return just an integer it worked, so I am almost certain it is the relation access causing the issue. Is there a way to do this that is better?

Comment: How is your workorder to load relationship defined?

Comment: The normal way:

`public function workorder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\WorkOrder', 'work_order_id');
    }`

Comment: Have you checked both your laravel.log and your php_error.log? Is it taking a while before it returns the 500 response?

Comment: @RossWilson This is on homestead, I checked /var/log/php7.1-fpm.log but there is nothing in there to help. I have definitely checked the laravel.log, I have it set to daily and it hasn't even created one for today yet.

Comment: Is it taking a while to return the response? Have you got any with or appends defined in your workorder or loads models (I'm assuming loads is a relationship)?

Comment: @RossWilson I have resolved it, sort of. Rather than using the relation, I am just getting all loads that share a work order id. This for some reason works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally while defining calculated attributes, dependence on relationship should be avoided. So one way to achieve what you are trying is (as you mentioned solved) is to get all `loads` having the same `work_orderid` and proceed with it.

```
public function getLoadCountAttribute ()
{
    $id = $this->work_order_id;
    return static::where('work_order_id', $id)->count();
}
```

Another way, more logical I guess, would be to define a relationship and eager load

```
//define a relation in your Load model  
public function load_count ()
{
    return count($this->workorder->loads)
    //-1  if you want to exclude the current load from count
    ;
}

//Then use Load::with('load_count') to eager load the load_count
//You may also use global scope
```

Yet another way would be to define a static function on `Workorder` model, which will accept an `id` and return the load_count

```
//Workorder model
public static function getLoadCount($id)
{
    $workorder = static::findOrFail($id);
    return count($workorder->loads);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code you wrote is correct as in it works but it has nothing to do with the actual purpose of what my code is. I don't need the count of loads, I needed the position of a load in the set of loads sharing a workorder.

Comment: @Fireynis Sorry my bad, I misunderstood your requirement due to the counter in your code. Wouldn't it be more simplified if you added a `position` field/attribute to you `loads` table/model which you can set using a model observer creating event. Then you won't have to make a new query to get the position. - just a suggestion.

Comment: that is what I ended up doing. I was just more curious as to way the crashing was occurring, which seemed to be due to using the relationship.